# Convert SQL Query in HQL (Hibernate)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jsp, hql

I have an SQL query that uses `NOT EXISTS`. How To convert this query TO HQL?

This is my Method:

```
public List<Cage> getByOwnerId(final Long ownerId, final String agriYearId)
    {
       return ((List<Cage>)getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback(){
            public Object doInHibernate(Session session){
                String queryString ="select "
                                    +"from tbl_cage c, tbl_actor a, tbl_owner o, tbl_inscasecode i, tbl_country co, tbl_inscasecode g , tbl_code cd"
                                    +" where "
                                    +" i.pk_inscasecodeid = c.FK_CAGETYPE"
                                    +" and cd.PK_CODEID=c.FK_CURRENCY "
                                    +" and co.PK_COUNTRYID = c.fk_country "
                                    +" and G.PK_INSCASECODEID=C.FK_CAGE_INSTALLATIONLOCATION "
                                    +" and c.FK_OWNER = o.PK_OWNERID " 
                                    +" and c.FK_OWNER=:ownerId "
                                    +" and "
                                    + "not exists (select 1 from tbl_policy, tbl_fishpolicy_cage "
                                    +" where c.PK_CAGEID = tbl_fishpolicy_cage.FK_CAGE "
                                    +" and tbl_fishpolicy_cage.FK_FISHPOLICY = tbl_policy.PK_POLICYID AND (tbl_policy.FK_CODEID = '018008' OR tbl_policy.FK_CODEID ='018007' OR tbl_policy.FK_CODEID ='018013' OR tbl_policy.FK_CODEID ='018014') "
                                    +" and tbl_policy.FK_AGRIYEARID=:agriYearId) "
                                    +" and c.PRIMITIVE_COST>0 and c.CAGE_ISDESTROY=0";
                Query query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
                List<Cage> returnList;
                query.setParameter("ownerId", ownerId);
                query.setParameter("agriYearId",agriYearId);
                returnList=query.list();
                return returnList;
    }}));
}
```

When I Use `List<Object>`, I can not iterate in jsp page, and when I use `List<Cage>` I got this error: `can not cast Object to Cage`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't return instances of the Cage entity. It returns individual fields from this entity. The result of such a query is a List, each Object[] containing all the selected fields

Queries can return multiple objects and/or properties as an array of type Object So try to parsing.

try this,

```
  returnList = (List<Cage>)session.createSQLQuery(queryString)
                         .setParameter("ownerId", ownerId)
                         .setParameter("agriYearId",agriYearId).list();
```